# Can you use both Azure Active Directory and Okta for SSO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We support multiple clients on a single Snowflake instance and I setup Azure Ad with the Snowflake app to enable SSO about a year ago. Today I was asked how one of our clients who uses Okta for their authentication how they would go about setting that up. I sent them the documentation but I want to be sure when I get down to step 3 that the Alter statement doesn't blow out my Azure Active Directory configuration.
Step 3:

ALTER ACCOUNT SET SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER =
'{ "certificate": "<Certificate_body>", -- Paste Certificate string with removed EOL charachters here
"ssoUrl": "https://my_okta_account.okta.com/app/snowflake/exhsddg0n8dixjoTjO0h7/sso/saml"", -- Okta SSO URL you captured in Step 1
"type" : "OKTA",
"label" : "MYSSO" -- Label of SSO button on Snowflake Web Login dialog
}';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, only one SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER can be configured for the Snowflake account.  I verified with my test account that running the `ALTER ACCOUNT SET SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER` statement you've shown would replace your Okta IdP configuration with Azure AD IdP.